# Mute feature in NAudio (waveOut)

Tags: c#, naudio

How to mute a `WaveOut`? I know I can save current volume to variable, then set `Volume` to `0f`. To unmute I just read that saved variable. However in Windows Volume Control panel it not shows "mute icon". Is any way to mute output just telling it to that system which is using `WaveOut`? Subquestion: `DirectSoundOut` uses DirectX, `AsioOut` uses Asio driver, and what is using `WaveOut`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't see the mute icon because it is not muting your soundcard for all applications, just for the instance of `WaveOut` you are using. This is because NAudio is passing the handle to [waveOutSetVolume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa908146.aspx), not the device identifier. You could call `WaveInterop.waveOutSetVolume` directly with the device identifier.